# Extracting a field from RESTORE HEADERONLY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, restore

I'm trying to use '[RESTORE HEADERONLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238455%28SQL.80%29.aspx)' to get the date when the backup I'm about to restore was made.

The command:

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = '<path to .bak file>'
```

works fine in Query Analyzer and gives a resultset with something like 50 columns.

The problem is actually accessing this from code.

I can get this into a temp table by declaring every single one of the 50:ish columns, inserting into it with `exec` and getting the value I want from there.

The problem is that I really want to avoid having to declare the entire resultset as a temp table as it seems like a very brittle solution if they ever add columns to it in future versions.

Is there any way to just get a single column out of this resultset without declaring all the columns?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works for me.

```
SELECT BackupStartDate 
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI',
                'Server=MARTINPC\MSSQL2008;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
'SET NOCOUNT ON;SET FMTONLY OFF;EXEC(''
RESTORE HEADERONLY 
FROM DISK = ''''C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQL2008\MSSQL\Backup\DB1.bak''''
'')'
)
```

The [ad hoc distributed queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187569.aspx) Option needs to be enabled. Or if you don't want to do that you can set up a loopback linked server and use that instead.

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'LOCALSERVER',  @srvproduct = '',
                        @provider = 'SQLOLEDB', @datasrc = @@servername

SELECT BackupStartDate 
FROM OPENQUERY(LOCALSERVER, 
               'SET FMTONLY OFF;
               EXEC(''
               RESTORE HEADERONLY 
               FROM DISK = ''''C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQL2008\MSSQL\Backup\DB1.bak''''
'')')
```

Comment: Clever, and thanks for sharing, but just for the record I think this is just as brittle/complex as the big-ole-list of columns in the end. Shame there's not an elegant solution.

Comment: @TimAbell - Yes I don't think I would actually use this in practice except maybe to get the table definition in the first place.

Comment: I couldn't make either query work.  
Does anyone else get the error message "The metadata could not be determined because statement RESTORE HEADERONLY... does not support metadata discovery" ? I believe `sp_describe_first_result_set` system sp is the culprit behind. I also raised this question as a separate ticket [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190954/error-in-using-sp-describe-first-result-set-with-restore)

Comment: @Stackoverflowuser - looks like I originally tested this against a 2008 instance (from `MARTINPC\MSSQL2008`) so maybe something has changed in later versions that means this no longer works.

Comment: @Stackoverflowuser, the above example works when server @@version < 2012. Starting with 2012, instead of executing this query, you can see in Profiler this one: exec [sys].sp_describe_first_result_set N'SET FMTONLY OFF;
               EXEC(''
               RESTORE HEADERONLY 
               FROM DISK = ''''C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQL2008\MSSQL\Backup\DB1.bak''''
'')',NULL,1

Comment: @sepupic and Martin: Do you have any suggestions\alternatives for this kind of query to work on versions > 2012? It is especially compelling in regards to clear code and not involving lengthy way of creating temp table and dropping it afterwards?

Answer (score 10):

Since you only asked about accessing the data from 'code' without specifying any details what sort of code, I hereby present the **PowerShell** solution:

```
Invoke-SQLcmd -Query "RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'R:\SQLFiles\MSSQL.MSSQLSERVER.Backup\Backup.bak'" | Select-Object MachineName,DatabaseName,HasBackupChecksums,BackupStartDate,BackupFinishDate
```

Comment: This is even better, as we can do something like ` ls | % { $_.fullname } |  % { invoke-sqlcmd -Query "RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = '$_'" } | format-table `

Comment: very nice indeed !

Answer (score 9):

The old-fashioned way, for reference:

```sql
declare @backupFile varchar(max) = 'C:\backupfile.bak';
declare @dbName varchar(256);

-- THIS IS SPECIFIC TO SQL SERVER 2012
--
declare @headers table 
( 
    BackupName varchar(256),
    BackupDescription varchar(256),
    BackupType varchar(256),        
    ExpirationDate varchar(256),
    Compressed varchar(256),
    Position varchar(256),
    DeviceType varchar(256),        
    UserName varchar(256),
    ServerName varchar(256),
    DatabaseName varchar(256),
    DatabaseVersion varchar(256),        
    DatabaseCreationDate varchar(256),
    BackupSize varchar(256),
    FirstLSN varchar(256),
    LastLSN varchar(256),        
    CheckpointLSN varchar(256),
    DatabaseBackupLSN varchar(256),
    BackupStartDate varchar(256),
    BackupFinishDate varchar(256),        
    SortOrder varchar(256),
    CodePage varchar(256),
    UnicodeLocaleId varchar(256),
    UnicodeComparisonStyle varchar(256),        
    CompatibilityLevel varchar(256),
    SoftwareVendorId varchar(256),
    SoftwareVersionMajor varchar(256),        
    SoftwareVersionMinor varchar(256),
    SoftwareVersionBuild varchar(256),
    MachineName varchar(256),
    Flags varchar(256),        
    BindingID varchar(256),
    RecoveryForkID varchar(256),
    Collation varchar(256),
    FamilyGUID varchar(256),        
    HasBulkLoggedData varchar(256),
    IsSnapshot varchar(256),
    IsReadOnly varchar(256),
    IsSingleUser varchar(256),        
    HasBackupChecksums varchar(256),
    IsDamaged varchar(256),
    BeginsLogChain varchar(256),
    HasIncompleteMetaData varchar(256),        
    IsForceOffline varchar(256),
    IsCopyOnly varchar(256),
    FirstRecoveryForkID varchar(256),
    ForkPointLSN varchar(256),        
    RecoveryModel varchar(256),
    DifferentialBaseLSN varchar(256),
    DifferentialBaseGUID varchar(256),        
    BackupTypeDescription varchar(256),
    BackupSetGUID varchar(256),
    CompressedBackupSize varchar(256),        
    Containment varchar(256),
    --
    -- This field added to retain order by
    --
    Seq int NOT NULL identity(1,1)
); 

insert into @headers exec('restore headeronly from disk = '''+ @backupFile +'''');
select @dbName = DatabaseName from @headers;
select @dbName;
```

Comment: To get this to work in SQL2014, you'll need to have these additional fields at the end of the table :
,Containment tinyint
,KeyAlgorithm nvarchar(32)
,EncryptorThumbprint varbinary(20)
,EncryptorType nvarchar(32)

Comment: There is also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31318785/450750), which doesn't use varchar for everything, and includes the extra columns for SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Note that these extra columns were actually added in SQL 2014 **SP1**.  I believe the Build Version for that is `12.0.4100.1`.

Answer (score 8):

This is a version independent sp I wrote to get the backup date from a file.

It's tested for SQL 2008R2, 2012 and 2014.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = 'spGetBackupDateFromFile')
    EXEC ('CREATE PROC dbo.spGetBackupDateFromFile AS SELECT ''stub version, to be replaced''')
GO
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------
                    spGetBackupDateFromFile
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Versie      : 1.0
Autheur     : Theo Ekelmans 
Datum       : 2016-03-31
Change      : Initial release 
------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
alter procedure dbo.spGetBackupDateFromFile(@BackupFile as varchar(1000), @DT as datetime output) as 

declare @BackupDT datetime
declare @sql varchar(8000)
declare @ProductVersion NVARCHAR(128)
declare @ProductVersionNumber TINYINT

SET @ProductVersion = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128),SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion'))
SET @ProductVersionNumber = SUBSTRING(@ProductVersion, 1, (CHARINDEX('.', @ProductVersion) - 1))

if object_id('dbo.tblBackupHeader') is not null drop table dbo.tblBackupHeader

set @sql = ''

-- THIS IS GENERIC FOR SQL SERVER 2008R2, 2012 and 2014
if @ProductVersionNumber in(10, 11, 12)
set @sql = @sql +'
create table dbo.tblBackupHeader
( 
    BackupName varchar(256),
    BackupDescription varchar(256),
    BackupType varchar(256),        
    ExpirationDate varchar(256),
    Compressed varchar(256),
    Position varchar(256),
    DeviceType varchar(256),        
    UserName varchar(256),
    ServerName varchar(256),
    DatabaseName varchar(256),
    DatabaseVersion varchar(256),        
    DatabaseCreationDate varchar(256),
    BackupSize varchar(256),
    FirstLSN varchar(256),
    LastLSN varchar(256),        
    CheckpointLSN varchar(256),
    DatabaseBackupLSN varchar(256),
    BackupStartDate varchar(256),
    BackupFinishDate varchar(256),        
    SortOrder varchar(256),
    CodePage varchar(256),
    UnicodeLocaleId varchar(256),
    UnicodeComparisonStyle varchar(256),        
    CompatibilityLevel varchar(256),
    SoftwareVendorId varchar(256),
    SoftwareVersionMajor varchar(256),        
    SoftwareVersionMinor varchar(256),
    SoftwareVersionBuild varchar(256),
    MachineName varchar(256),
    Flags varchar(256),        
    BindingID varchar(256),
    RecoveryForkID varchar(256),
    Collation varchar(256),
    FamilyGUID varchar(256),        
    HasBulkLoggedData varchar(256),
    IsSnapshot varchar(256),
    IsReadOnly varchar(256),
    IsSingleUser varchar(256),        
    HasBackupChecksums varchar(256),
    IsDamaged varchar(256),
    BeginsLogChain varchar(256),
    HasIncompleteMetaData varchar(256),        
    IsForceOffline varchar(256),
    IsCopyOnly varchar(256),
    FirstRecoveryForkID varchar(256),
    ForkPointLSN varchar(256),        
    RecoveryModel varchar(256),
    DifferentialBaseLSN varchar(256),
    DifferentialBaseGUID varchar(256),        
    BackupTypeDescription varchar(256),
    BackupSetGUID varchar(256),
    CompressedBackupSize varchar(256),'

-- THIS IS SPECIFIC TO SQL SERVER 2012
if @ProductVersionNumber in(11)
set @sql = @sql +'
    Containment varchar(256),'


-- THIS IS SPECIFIC TO SQL SERVER 2014
if @ProductVersionNumber in(12)
set @sql = @sql +'
    Containment tinyint, 
    KeyAlgorithm nvarchar(32), 
    EncryptorThumbprint varbinary(20), 
    EncryptorType nvarchar(32),'


--All versions (This field added to retain order by)
set @sql = @sql +'
    Seq int NOT NULL identity(1,1)
); 
'
exec (@sql)


set @sql = 'restore headeronly from disk = '''+ @BackupFile +'''' 

insert into dbo.tblBackupHeader 
exec(@sql)

select @DT = BackupStartDate from dbo.tblBackupHeader 

if object_id('dbo.tblBackupHeader') is not null drop table dbo.tblBackupHeader
```

Comment: As per http://stackoverflow.com/a/31318785/489865 and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3058865, the KeyAlgorithm/EncryptorThumbprint/EncryptorType  you have added for "SQL SERVER 2014" actually only appeared in SP1.  I believe the Build Version for that is `12.0.4100.1`, so code ought to look at all the fields in `SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')` to cater correctly for that.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is working fine on Linux ;-)

So, this is my own solution for filelistonly (working too for any of the auxiliary statements):

```
sqlcmd -U *** -P *** -Q "restore filelistonly FROM DISK = '/tmp/backup.bak';" -o /tmp/metadata.out
tr -s ' ' < /tmp/metadata.out | cut -d' ' -f1,2,3,4,5 | tail -n +3 | head -n -2
```

Answer (score -2):

declare @mybackup sysname = 'F:\testbak\test.bak'
declare @major int = CAST(PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS NVARCHAR(128)),4) as int)
declare @build int = CAST(PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS NVARCHAR(128)),2) as int)
declare @AcceptableDaysOld int = 7

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Header') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Header

if ( @major >= 10 ) --must be equal or newer than 2008 to meet this criteria!
create table #Header
(
BackupName varchar(256),
BackupDescription varchar(256),
BackupType varchar(256),
ExpirationDate varchar(256),
Compressed varchar(256),
Position varchar(256),
DeviceType varchar(256),
UserName varchar(256),
ServerName varchar(256),
DatabaseName varchar(256),
DatabaseVersion varchar(256),
DatabaseCreationDate varchar(256),
BackupSize varchar(256),
FirstLSN varchar(256),
LastLSN varchar(256),
CheckpointLSN varchar(256),
DatabaseBackupLSN varchar(256),
BackupStartDate varchar(256),
BackupFinishDate varchar(256),
SortOrder varchar(256),
CodePage varchar(256),
UnicodeLocaleId varchar(256),
UnicodeComparisonStyle varchar(256),
CompatibilityLevel varchar(256),
SoftwareVendorId varchar(256),
SoftwareVersionMajor varchar(256),
SoftwareVersionMinor varchar(256),
SoftwareVersionBuild varchar(256),
MachineName varchar(256),
Flags varchar(256),
BindingID varchar(256),
RecoveryForkID varchar(256),
Collation varchar(256),
FamilyGUID varchar(256),
HasBulkLoggedData varchar(256),
IsSnapshot varchar(256),
IsReadOnly varchar(256),
IsSingleUser varchar(256),
HasBackupChecksums varchar(256),
IsDamaged varchar(256),
BeginsLogChain varchar(256),
HasIncompleteMetaData varchar(256),
IsForceOffline varchar(256),
IsCopyOnly varchar(256),
FirstRecoveryForkID varchar(256),
ForkPointLSN varchar(256),
RecoveryModel varchar(256),
DifferentialBaseLSN varchar(256),
DifferentialBaseGUID varchar(256),
BackupTypeDescription varchar(256),
BackupSetGUID varchar(256),
CompressedBackupSize varchar(256)
)

if ( @major >= 11 ) --ADD TO ACCOMODATE SQL 2012
ALTER TABLE #Header add Containment varchar(256)

if ( @major = 12 and @build >= 4100 ) OR (@major >= 13) --ADD TO ACCOMODATE SQL 2014 SP1 through SQL 2019
ALTER TABLE #Header add
KeyAlgorithm nvarchar(32),
EncryptorThumbprint varbinary(20),
EncryptorType nvarchar(32)

--All versions (This field added to retain order by)
ALTER TABLE #Header add
Seq int NOT NULL identity(1,1)
insert into #Header
EXEC('RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK=''' +@mybackup+ '''')

IF (select TOP 1 BackupStartDate from #Header order by BackupStartDate DESC) < GETDATE()-@AcceptableDaysOld
print 'This is an old backup!'
ELSE
print 'This is a recent backup'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Header') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Header

Comment: This is literally the opposite of what the OP asked (10 years ago too).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).